# How to track if (List<T>)collection is modified?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have a my custom collection derived from List(.MyItem.)

I want to trace if my collection is modified, how can I do that?

I am able to track Add Remove operations etc...by implement new definition of them but I don't  see any method in List that gives me opportunity to track if collection is modified...

Comment: "modified" here means the whole list was modified? e.g. a new item is added/removed? or it means an item in the list is modified?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at a new type called [ObservableCollection<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx).  It has built in notification of changes, and it should be fairly simple to change your base class to this from list as both are very similar.

Comment: The VS2008 not able to recognize ObservableCollection<T>..

I have included the namespace using System.Collections.Generic;
I see only three collection under System.Collection.ObjectModel:
1.Collection
2.Keyed Collection
3.ReadOnlyCollection..
what am I missing ???????

Comment: Add a reference to WindowsBase.dll.

Comment: @Skeet: Relatively new, that is.  If it weren't, he wouldn't be asking this question, and no one would need to point him at the correct assembly.  But, thanks anyway for the "Skeet bump".  :-)